# What is Expression tree in data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

What is expression tree and how it is evaluated? Does it get evaluated in top-down and left-right manner?

Comment: Suppose you evaluated it top-down. So, you evaluate the root node first. But how? You don't have the values of its operands yet.

Answer (score 2):

Binary expression tree is evaluated from leaves to a root, usually from left to right (for arithmetical operations. it depends on type of expressions and tree) - often, recursively.

This image can help you in understanding the main principles of Expression tree:

[image]

However, this question is too simple and broad. Please, next time, review the question and ask a question **only** if it is specific and has no answer in the Internet.

There are many articles in the Internet concerning this topic beginning from [Wikipedia article with algorithm and examples in pseudo-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) and ending with many other articles.

Answer (score 1):

Expression tree is just a representation of any algebraic expression as nodes of binary tree. Depending on how your expression is, you will choose the traversal to evaluate your tree (and create it of course).

If your original algebraic expression is `standard algebraic expression`, do `in-order traversal`.

If it is `prefix algebraic expression`, you do `pre-order traversal`.

Or if it is `post-fix`, you do `post-order traversal` on the binary tree.

--for both creation and evaluation of the tree.

EDIT: The answer given by @YeldarKurmangaliyev is a show for standard algebraic expression, so the tree is created (and evaluated) using inorder traversal.

Answer (score 0):

An expression tree is an expression that is shown/converted by/as tree.

e.g.

x = (y + 4) * 2

can be shown as

```
     *
  /    \ 
  +    2
/  \
y  4
```

Mostly evaluation is from left to right, it can be seen from the tree immediately. If the evaluation order is different, the tree would look different.

Comment: `y` at the root must not be there.